# Linked List SortedInsert() function

Tags: c, linked-list

I using C wrote a SortedInsert() function to insert a new node to a given list that is sorted in increasing order. My code of SortedInsert() function is following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>


struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void push(struct node** head, int data_new) {
    struct node* headNode;
    headNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    headNode->data = data_new;
    headNode->next = *head;
    *head = headNode;
}

struct node* BuildFunny() {
    struct node*head = NULL;
    push(&head, 2);
    push(&head->next, 3);
    push(&head->next->next, 8);
    push(&head->next->next->next, 10);
    push(&head->next->next->next->next, 15);
    head->next->next->next->next->next = NULL;

    return head;
}

void SortedInsert(struct node** headRef, struct node* newNode){
    if (*headRef == NULL || (*headRef)->data >= newNode->data){
        newNode->next = *headRef;
        *headRef = newNode;
    }
    else {
        struct node* current;
        current = *headRef;
        while (current->next->data <= newNode->data && current->next != NULL){
            current = current->next;
        }
        newNode->next = current->next;
        current->next = newNode;
    }
}
```

The main function is:

```
int main()
{
    struct node* head;
    head = BuildFunny();
    struct node* newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->data = 1;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    SortedInsert(&head, newNode);

    struct node* newNode1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode1->data = 6;
    newNode1->next = NULL;
    SortedInsert(&head, newNode1);

    /*
    struct node* newNode2 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode2->data = 20;
    newNode2->next = NULL;
    SortedInsert(&head, newNode2);
    */

    while(head != NULL){
        printf("%d ", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The problem is I can correctly insert number 1 and 6 into the list with correct order, however number 20 always gives me error (uncomment newNode2 will gives error). I have no idea why I can't insert number that over 15 into my list. Could someone help me to make numbers that over 15 also be able to insert at the end of the list?

Comment: "gives error". It would help if you actually told us what the error is. Is it a compile error? A runtime error? And what are the error messages if any?

Answer (score 1):

Might be problem is with this condition

```
while (current->next->data <= newNode->data && current->next != NULL)
```

Change it to check for `NULL` before

```
while (current->next != NULL && (current->next->data <= newNode->data))
```

With your code, when `current->next` is `NULL` it will try the first condition which will refer to `NULL` pointer causing issues.
So you will get problem when adding higher number than existing numbers in the list.